# Copy range of lines from textfile

Tags: vbscript

How to copy lines **4** to **8** and **24** to **28** from textfileA then write them to textFileB using VBScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [`Line`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chsfhd43%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property when reading the the input file. Example:

```
...
Do Until inputFile.AtEndOfStream
  If inputFile.Line >= 4 And inputFile.Line <= 8 Then
    outputFile.WriteLine inputFile.ReadLine
  Else
    inputFile.SkipLine
  End If
Loop
...
```